# Integrate data from a Java EE application to Microsoft Dynamics GP

Tags: dynamics-gp

I am working on a project to integrate accounting data like receipts, invoices, etc from a Java EE system into Microsoft Dynamics GP 2010. The database is MySQL. Please share your thoughts on which which approach works best. I have searched around and there are 2 approaches: Integration Manager, eConnect via Web Services.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have two legitimate options - eConnect via GP Web Services or eConnect via SQL Stored Procedures. I wouldn't consider using Integration Manager as it cannot be automated and requires someone to log into Dynamics GP before using it.

The most simple integration point would be to call the eConnect SQL Stored Procedures directly at the database level. For each eConnect integration object, there is a corresponding SQL Stored procedure. You simply call the procedure and pass it the proper values into its parameter. Creating an invoice in Dynamics GP, for example, can be done by calling the procedures for creating SOP Document headers, lines, and distributions.

On the other hand, if you are prepared to spend a little extra time installing the GP Web Services then you can integrate with that and maintain a service oriented architecture. Most of the same functionality is available via the web services but it is a subset of the features available in the eConnect procedures. In return, you get all of the benefits of a SOA architecture.

Ultimately it depends on your plans for overall architecture in your environment. Either method should work fine for your requirements. If this is the only integration into GP I might chose the more simple method of eConnect stored procedures. If you plan to integrate other applications into Dynamics GP you may want to take the time to invest in using the services.